# PHP MySQL Dropdown box

Tags: php, mysql, forms, dropdownbox

I have a dropdown box which is populated through MySQL:

```
echo "<form>";<br>
echo "Please Select Your Event<br />";
echo "<select>";
$results = mysql_query($query)
    or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo "<option>";
    echo $row['eventname'];
    echo "</option>";
    }   
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Go'>";
echo "</form>";
```

How do i make it that if one clicks submit it will display a value from a MySQL db

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you want it to display the value on the page that submitted was clicked on, or on the page that the submit button leads to?

Comment: on the same page would be better. Basically the value for the dropdown is $row['eventname']; When selected or submited it displays the value $row['result']; Those two values are already connected using a SQL query.

Comment: Just an FYI, it may be easier to just add the loop between the `<select>..</select>` tags in regular HTML, rather than echoing each tag -- unless that was just for posting on here. Also, may want to check out jQuery's Ajax capabilities - www.jquery.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Give a name to your `<select>`, i.e. `<select name='event'>`.

2) Redirect your form to the display page (and set method POST): `<form method='POST' action='display.php'>`

3) just display the selected value: `<?php echo $_POST['event']; ?>`

---

If you want to use the same page, give a name to your submit button and then do this:

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit']))
      echo $_POST['event'];
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So i can post a value to the same page it came from. Then the page just reloads and i pull the value from the post?

Comment: But remember to use htmlspecialchars before printing anything. Otherwise there is risk of XSS attack

Answer (score 1):

Just change your query like `SELECT result FROM somedb WHERE eventname = '".$eventname."'`

Then you just do: (remember to check before while has user already requested info)

```
The value was: <?php print $row["result"]; ?>
```

Remember to check `$_POST["eventname"]` with htmlspecialchars before inserting it to query.